# Is there a way to pass an imported component through a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a library called SlidingPane, and each pane has the exact same styles, just different content depending on the page. So I want to put it into a separate page, and get the content through an argument:

```js
export default function CustomSlidingPane(content){
    <SlidingPane
        className="slidingPanel"
        isOpen={state.isPaneOpen}
        onRequestClose={() => {
            setState({ isPaneOpen: false });
        }}
        >
        <Container>
            {content}
        </Container>
    </SlidingPane>
}
```

All of the content is in separate `.js` pages that kind of look like this:

```js
export default function One() {
    return (
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    );
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is pass one of the content functions through to the CustomSlidingPane like this:

```js
import One from './One';
import CustomSlidingPane from './CustomSlidingPane';

export default function Main(){
    <Container>
        <CustomSlidingPane content={<One/>}>
    </Container>
}
```

Every thing I've tried always ends up in content being undefined. Is there any proper way to do this / is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use children prop here. I am adding an example with a simple `div` element.

```
export default function CustomSlidingPane(props) {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}
```

Content will be same as you defined in your example:

```
export default function One() {
  return <h1>Hello</h1>;
}
```

This is how you can pass the content to your slidingPlane component:

```
export default function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomSlidingPane>
        <One />
      </CustomSlidingPane>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I got it working a little while back and meant to comment, but stackoverflow went under maintenance for a bit.
What I ended up doing was assigning everything in an object, then calling stuff through the object, and that ended up working.
While this wasn't exactly the solution that fixed my problem, it set me on the right track, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. It looks like you mighthave forgotten a `return` in `CustomSlidingPane`
2. You need to destructure `content` from the props

Try this

```
export default function CustomSlidingPane({content}){
    return (
        <SlidingPane
        className="slidingPanel"
        isOpen={state.isPaneOpen}
        onRequestClose={() => {
            setState({ isPaneOpen: false });
        }}
        >
        <Container>
            {content}
        </Container>
    </SlidingPane>
    )
}
```

Also, this pattern might be supported better with the `children` prop.